# URLSearchParams returns empty from within an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

My iframe is:

```
<iframe src="iframe.html?name=%1A%C3%A9%C2%AB%C2%A1%C2%A7O%C2%AE%C2%87nr%C3%9D" allowtransparency="allowtransparency" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; z-index: 9999; position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; border: 0;"></iframe>
```

And from within `iframe.html`, I'm doing:

```
    let urlParams = new URLSearchParams(document.location.search)
    console.log(urlParams)
```

However, this always returns `URLSearchParams {}__proto__: URLSearchParams`

Empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`URLSearchParams` is not a plain object, so you need to use methods to get params,
for example

```
console.log(urlParams.get('name'));
```

### All methods are:

This interface doesn't inherit any methods.

```
URLSearchParams.append()
```

Appends a specified key/value pair as a new search parameter.

```
URLSearchParams.delete()
```

Deletes the given search parameter, and its associated value, from the list of all search parameters.

```
URLSearchParams.entries()
```

Returns an iterator allowing iteration through all key/value pairs contained in this object.

```
URLSearchParams.forEach()
```

Allows iteration through all values contained in this object via a callback function.

```
URLSearchParams.get()
```

Returns the first value associated with the given search parameter.

```
URLSearchParams.getAll()
```

Returns all the values associated with a given search parameter.

```
URLSearchParams.has()
```

Returns a Boolean indicating if such a given parameter exists.

```
URLSearchParams.keys()
```

Returns an iterator allowing iteration through all keys of the key/value pairs     contained in this object.

```
URLSearchParams.set()
```

Sets the value associated with a given search parameter to the given value. If there are several values, the others are deleted.

```
URLSearchParams.sort()
```

Sorts all key/value pairs, if any, by their keys.

```
URLSearchParams.toString()
```

Returns a string containing a query string suitable for use in a URL.

```
URLSearchParams.values()
```

Returns an iterator allowing iteration through all values of the key/value pairs contained in this object.

[MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)